# How to test X11 Forwarding?

Tags: x11forwarding

I am trying to enable X11 forwarding so that I can run Firefox from the remote host. The remote host is a Vagrant VM running Ubuntu 12.04. The local host is Mac OS X 10.10. I think I have everything configured correctly, but I've never done this before, and it doesn't seem to be working.

What is an easy way to test that X11 forwarding is configured correctly?

Comment: Try running Firefox?

Comment: Sorry, I was simplifying the example...I'm actually trying to run selenium which is supposed to start firefox behind the scenes, but I'm not sure where things are going wrong. When I run `firefox` on the remote host, I get `Error: no display specified`

Comment: Then everything isn't configured correctly. Perhaps you should ask your question about that, instead.

Comment: So you're saying, all I need to do is try to run `firefox` and it should work? You should make that comment an answer because that's all I need to know. I don't know if I need to start an X window session or specify any additional command line options, so that's why I am asking this question. If I can get a simple example working, then I can move onto getting the selenium configuration working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply running a graphical program when logged into the remote host is a sufficient test.

Comment: e.g. `ssh host firefox` (assuming firefox is installed on the host)